# Jwt token vertification

Tags: jwt, token

Good day, I am trying to do JWT authentication and was following tutorial, but have few questions.

AuthResponseDto class

```
 public class AuthResponseDto
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

VerifyRefreshToken function

```
public async Task<AuthResponseDto> VerifyRefreshToken(AuthResponseDto request)
    {
        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenContent = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(request.Token);
        var userName = tokenContent.Claims.ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email)?.Value;
        _user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if(_user == null || _user.Id != request.UserId)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var isValidRefreshToken = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(_user,
            _loginProvider, _refreshToken, request.RefreshToken);

        if (isValidRefreshToken)
        {
            var token = await GenerateToken();
            return new AuthResponseDto
            {
                Token = token,
                UserId = _user.Id,
                RefreshToken = await CreateRefreshToken()
            };
        }

        await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(_user);

        return null;
    }
```

GenerateToken Function

```
private async Task<string> GenerateToken()
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            _configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]));

        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_user);

        var rolesClaims = roles.Select(r => new Claim(
            ClaimTypes.Role,
            r
            )).ToList();

        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(_user);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, _user.Email),
            new Claim("uid", _user.Id)
        }.Union(userClaims).Union(rolesClaims);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(
                Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["JwtSettings:DurationInMinutes"])),
            signingCredentials: credentials
         );


        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

As you can see I added expires in my token, but then it hits "VerifyRefreshToken" I don't see any check logic for it. Does it still check for time then validating it or I need to add that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In verifyRefreshToken added this

```
        var utcExpiryDate = long.Parse(tokenContent.Claims.ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp)?.Value);
        var expiryDate = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(utcExpiryDate);

        if(expiryDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            return new AuthResponseDto()
            {
                Token = "0",
                RefreshToken = "0",
                UserId = "0"
            };
        }
```

and created new private functions

```
private DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
    {
        var dateTimeVal = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dateTimeVal = dateTimeVal.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToUniversalTime();

        return dateTimeVal;
    }
```

Everything works now